# plot mean value of a signal for confidence interval

Tags: matlab, plot, mean, confidence-interval

i have a signal on y axis (yawrate) and a time signal on x axis (time). I tried to find the confidence interval of this signal. But i can't plot mean value of signal. I think because mean value has 2 vectors but signal size is 5001. How can i solve that? I appreciated for answers!

```
N = size(yawrate,1);  % Number of ‘Experiments’ In Data Set

yMean = mean(yawrate);  % Mean Of All Experiments At Each Value Of ‘time’`

ySEM = std(yawrate)/sqrt(N);  % Compute ‘Standard Error Of The Mean’ Of All Experiments At Each Value Of ‘time’

CI95 = tinv([0.025  0.975], N-1);  % t-score Calculate 95% Probability Intervals Of t-Distribution

yCI95 = bsxfun(@times, ySEM, CI95(:));  % Calculate 95% Confidence Intervals Of All Experiments At Each Value Of ‘x’         

figure

plot(time, yMean)   % Plot Mean Of All Experiments

hold on

plot(time, yCI95+yMean)  % Plot 95% Confidence Intervals Of All Experiments

hold off

grid
```

Comment: What are sizes of `yawrate` and `time`? What does “mean value has 2 vectors“ mean?

Comment: Thanks a lot your answer. Size of yawrate and time is 5001. I mean size of mean value show 1 1.

Comment: The code is written for a `yawrate` that is a `NxM` matrix, with `M` time steps and `N` experiments. In that case, `mean(yawrate)` is a vector with `M` values. `time` needs to have `M` values as well. If your `N` is 1, this code is not useful.

Comment: no, my N is 5001.

Comment: No, your `M` is 5001, your `N` is 1.

Comment: Thanks Cris, you are right. Actually that is my question. How should i plot the upper and lower boundaries of my signal according to confidence interval?

Comment: If you have only one signal, you cannot compute a confidence interval. If you know something about how the signal was measured/obtained, you can estimate a confidence interval, but that is not a computational thing, and requires a good understanding of the underlying physics of the measured process and the measurement equipment. Easiest is to simply measure your signal multiple times, and put the collection of signals through the code you have here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment, but i don't heve enough reputarion. Since I'm *answering*, I'll also use what's already in the comments. The question is bit unclear regarding the things already pointed out in the comments: `size(yawrate)` is `[1,N]`  or `[N,M]` for some M? Same questions stands for `time`. If I understand correctly from your answer to that and from your code, you assume that `yawrate` is `NxM` and `yMean` is size `1xM`. in that case, you'd need time to be `1xM` as well. This is what Cris Luengo wrote.

Also, `yCI95+yMean` would mean adding a `2x1` vector containing the confidence interval to the `1xM` values o `yMean`. That would give you a `2xM` array. That doesn't work in every Matlab version and I think it requires the firs one to be `2x1` and not `1x2`, so you might need to do

```
plot(time, yCI95(1)+yMean)
plot(time, yCI95(2)+yMean)
```

again, assuming I understand your code. Check for the size assumptions you are making.

Comment: Thank you Marcos. Actually i am asking, what you ask me for :) I don't understand confidence interval. I have signal and a graph of signal, like in this photo. Size(yawrate) and size(time) is [5001 1] but mean value is a number and size [1 1]. If i plot(time,mean), it is coming a surely a line. In this Situation how can i create a plot upper and lower boundaries of confidence interval? That is the point, i don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

yMean seems to be a single value so when you plot it you would get a dot for every time value. In case your sampling time is too large, you may increase the visibility of your lines by using t=0:0.01:time(end) in the plot function rather than time.